# Best strategy for making API calls from stencil apps?

Tags: javascript, rest, stenciljs

I am trying to use the `npm init stencil` in app mode. however, this creates a static app, without any api like configuration.....

should I rely on a global variable to configure the baseURL for api endpoints?

should I provide this value as a parameter on the app-root element?

what is the best strategy for this?

Comment: I would love to have an answer for this as well, but I think it's primarily opinion based. There are various ways of solving globals, you might be looking for the more general term of "application state". For example there's `state-tunnel` (little buggy rn) or `redux` (verbose) and my favorite `mobx` in conjuction with something like `libx`. But it's really up to you.

Comment: I have started using @stencil/redux along with wrench for the actual calls. still not sure how to provide a base domain, since we will not be hosting the url on the same domain....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the @stencil/redux package, and then created a apiClient object that I appended as a reducer....

this would allow me to write my redux actions like this:

```
export function myApiAction(param1, param2) {
  return  (dispatch, getStore) => {

    const client = getStore().apiClient;
    //dostuff here
    client.makeRequest().then( res => {
       dispatch({type: MY_API_RESULT, data:blah});
    });
  };
}
```